# Can't open TIFF in camera raw/Nik Color EFX

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, tiff, layers

I'm editing a picture of the beach I shot and it has a few adjustment layers. I wanted to save it and then open it in Color EFX to make other adjustments (detail enhancer etc.) and in Camera RAW to change the color profile(I don't know how to do it in PS). It won't let me open it. It'll display the error ' Failed to open image'.  Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you ever read any user manuals/Instruction manuals/user guides for applications such as Photoshop/ACR, Color EFX, etc.?

Comment: @Michael Clark Do you think I would have asked if I had found the answer to my question in the user manual or a guide? This forum is full of smug people, seriously. I specifically said that it shows the error ' Failed to open image'.  Apparently, you don't the answer yourself. Why even ask in a forum when people aren't willing to help out. I found out myself anyway.

Comment: Congratulations on solving your problem. Please don't edit the answer into your question, though. Leave your question as is and add your solution as an answer. (yes, it's perfectly fine to answer your own question) Then accept that answer. This way your answer will be displayed as the correct one and your question will show up as answered, which makes it easier to find for people with the same problem. Thanks

Comment: @Chris I'm pretty sure the guides for Color EFX and Camera RAW mention that images must be flattened (all layers combined into a single layer) in order to be opened with those applications. I'm not trying to be smug. It just seems that most of your questions could be answered by doing a little bit of due diligence on your own with the obvious resources available to you.

Comment: Further, "Failed to open image" means just that. The reason could be any one of dozens of different issues. From incompatible file formats, to raw images in compatible file formats that are from new camera models not yet supported, to corrupted files, to files with multiple layers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Color Efex Pro does not work on RAW images natively. If you are starting from a RAW image with either Aperture or Lightroom, the application will generate a rasterized (RGB) image from your original RAW f ile and send it to Color Efex Pro.  You can use the Preferences for  Aperture and Lightroom to choose the file type, color profile, and resolution of exported images.

This is an exzerpt from the following PDF. [The Photographer’s Guide to Color Efex Pro 4](https://www.google.ch/url?q=http://www.luminescentphoto.com/cep4/content/Odell_CEP4_Guide_Excerpt.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwin4sD5tLPRAhUG1hQKHfNuAz4QFggNMAE&usg=AFQjCNEvCHKFBL8UDO9uAlxFjvv6naqrMw)